# fmt.Printf with width and precision fields in %g behaves unexpectedly

Tags: go, printf

I am trying to get some floats formatted with the same width using `fmt.Printf()`.

For example, given the float values 0.0606060606060606, 0.3333333333333333, 0.05, 0.4 and 0.1818181818181818, I would like to get each value formatted in, say, 10 runes:

```
0.06060606
0.33333333
      0.05
       0.4
0.18181818
```

But I can't understand how it's done. Documentation says that

> For floating-point values, width sets the minimum width of the field
>   and precision sets the number of places after the decimal, if
>   appropriate, except that for %g/%G it sets the total number of digits.
>   For example, given 123.45 the format %6.2f prints 123.45 while %.4g
>   prints 123.5. The default precision for %e and %f is 6; for %g it is
>   the smallest number of digits necessary to identify the value
>   uniquely.

So, if I use `%f` a larger number will not fit in 10-character constraint, therefore `%g` is required. To get a minimum width of 10 is `%10g` and to get a maximum number of 9 digits (+1 for the dot) it's `%.9g`, but combining them in `%10.9g` is not behaving as I expect

```
0.0606060606
0.333333333
      0.05
       0.4
0.181818182
```

How come I get strings which are of 10 runes, others that are 11 runes and others that are 12 runes?

In particular, it seems that `%.9g` does not produce 9 digits in total. See for example: http://play.golang.org/p/ie9k8bYC7r

Comment: Precision (as in `%.9g`) is the number of digits in the scientific notations (i.e. leading zeros are ignored). This is not very well documented, I suggest to file a bug at github.com/golang/go. Width (as in `%10g`) is the minimum number of runes to output according to the documentation. So the output looks correct.

Comment: Ah, therefore a `0.000123456789` is still be formatted using 13 digits using `%.9g`! Damn, that's not clear from the docs... "Total number of digits" is kinda misleading!

Comment: @AkiRoss you are right, Go's official documentation is really confusing on this :( I believe this question will help a lot of people.

Comment: I hope it will be useful. In general, I feel like that formatting is a not-so-straightforward topic. Here's the issue report https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15178

Comment: nice job @AkiRoss :D

Comment: Related / Possible duplicate of [Golang: is there any standard library to convert float64 to string with fix width with maximum number of significant digits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515818/golang-is-there-any-standard-library-to-convert-float64-to-string-with-fix-widt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, we need to understand the documentation correctly:

> width sets the minimum width of the field and precision sets the number of places after the decimal, if appropriate, except that for %g/%G it sets the total number of digits.

This line is grammatically correct, but the **it** in the last part of this sentence is really confusing: it actually refers to **the precision**, not the **width**.

Therefore, let's look at some examples:

```
123.45
12312.2
1.6069
0.6069
0.0006069
```

and you print it like `fmt.Printf("%.4g")`, it gives you

```
123.5
1.231e+04
1.607
0.6069
0.0006069
```

only 4 **digits, excluding all decimal points and exponent**. But wait, what happens to the last 2 example? Are you kidding me isn't that more than 5 digits?

This is the confusing part in printing: **leading 0s** won't be counted as digits, and **won't be shrunk when there are less than 4 zeros**.

Let's look at 0 behavior using the example below:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%.4g\n", 0.12345)
    fmt.Printf("%.4g\n", 0.012345)
    fmt.Printf("%.4g\n", 0.0012345)
    fmt.Printf("%.4g\n", 0.00012345)
    fmt.Printf("%.4g\n", 0.000012345)
    fmt.Printf("%.4g\n", 0.0000012345)
    fmt.Printf("%.4g\n", 0.00000012345)

    fmt.Printf("%g\n", 0.12345)
    fmt.Printf("%g\n", 0.012345)
    fmt.Printf("%g\n", 0.0012345)
    fmt.Printf("%g\n", 0.00012345)
    fmt.Printf("%g\n", 0.000012345)
    fmt.Printf("%g\n", 0.0000012345)
    fmt.Printf("%g\n", 0.00000012345)
}
```

and the output:

```
0.1235
0.01235
0.001234
0.0001234
1.234e-05
1.234e-06
1.235e-07
0.12345
0.012345
0.0012345
0.00012345
1.2345e-05
1.2345e-06
1.2345e-07
```

So you could see, when there are less than 4 leading 0s, they will be counted, and be shrunk if there are more than that.

Ok, next thing is the `width`. From the documentation, `width` only specifies the minimum width, **including decimal place and exponent**. Which means, if you have more digits than what `width` specified, it will shoot out of the width.

Remember, width will be taken account as the last step, which means it needs to **first satisfy the precision field**.

Let's go back to your case. You specified `%10.9g`, that means you want a total digit of 9, excluding the leading `0`, and a min width of `10` including decimal place and exponent, and the precision should take priority.

`0.0606060606060606`: take 9 digits without leading 0 will give you `0.0606060606`, since it's already 12 width, it passes the min width of 10;

`0.3333333333333333`: take 9 digits without leading 0 will give you `0.333333333`, since it's already 11 width, it passes the min width of 10;

`0.05`: take 9 digits without leading 0 will give you `0.05`, since it's less than width 10, it will pad with another 6 width to get width of 10;

`0.4`: same as above;

`0.1818181818181818`: take 9 digits without leading 0 will give you `0.181818182` with **rounding**, since it's already 11 width, it passes the min width of 10.

So this explains why you got the funny printing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree: it gives precedence to the "precision fields" not to "width".
So when we need fix columns for printing we need write new formatting func.

Comment: Simple Answer is "%10.5g" but it will not return maximum number of Significant Digits of float number

Comment: The OP is asking why, not looking for a solution :p

Comment: Yes, I agree. I think the fmt lib for Printf needs rewriting for providing more significant digits.
With float64 which provides 16 digits of significant digits it’s a little odd to loose significant digits for any reason. And give to length filed a little more respect in %L.Dg