# Maximum Float Width

Tags: go, floating-point, format

In go, the statement

```
fmt.Sprintf("%4.3f", 18.8836)
```

Will return

```
18.883
```

Is there a way of making the return value

```
18.88
```

In other words, is there a way to make the 4 apply to the whole width of the number and not just the decimal portion?

Comment: Related: [Golang: is there any standard library to convert float64 to string with fix width with maximum number of significant digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515818/golang-is-there-any-standard-library-to-convert-float64-to-string-with-fix-widt/36518167#36518167)

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this with `%g`:

```
fmt.Printf("%.4g\n", 18.8836)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/accWeNXG9V